# Please help, Struggling with induced EMF from magnets?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

The answer for b,i) is 0.353m^2s^-1

and answer for b,ii) is 0.353 * 0.005 =~1.8*10^-3V

I want to know why you only times T(magnetic flux density) by the one spoke? Is it because they are measuring it instantaneously, like at that moment where the spoke touches the connections and there is a 'spark' of induced emf? Or is something else is happening?
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EMF is induced across all of the spokes. The EMFs are in parallel so they do not add up. If there are 100 spokes the EMF is not 180 mV, it is still 1.8 mV, the same as across one spoke.

Comment: Do you mean that the emfs are parallel like in a parallel circuit where voltage is constant but current changes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you have many cells in parallel with each other, and the combination is in series with a resistor, the voltage across the resistor and the current through it are the same as when there is only one cell, but the current through each cell is smaller.

Comment: so in this case, the current increase with the number of spokes, while emf is constant?

Comment: Yes. More spokes, more current. The resistors are in parallel, so the total resistance is less.